# Replace string in Pandas column by substring from list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF:

```
DF
camp, value
asd_abcd_gr_yxz_aaaa, 5
efgh_kr_ijk, 10
hjssaasd_kr_adsad, 15
asdas_kr_asd, 2
asd_fr_asda_bb_bbbbbbb, 12
adklasdj_gr_asdsad, 3
```

and much longer.

After comparing with elements in list `[_gr_, _kr_, _fr_, etc..]` I want the result to be

```
DF
camp, value
gr, 8
kr, 27
fr, 12
```

preferably as short as possible without looping through the DF. The list is much longer than `_gr_, _kr_, _fr_`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry can you post raw input data, code to recreate your df and what the desired output df should look like. Are you saying you have a column with values like ` 'abcd_gr_yxz'` and if it contains anything in `gr` then you want to replace with `gr`?

Comment: Now it's edited @EdChum

Comment: So in this case would it be true that you want to always strip the leading and trailing words at the `_` underscore characters?

Comment: Sorry, my example wasn't general enough. There might exist several underscores :/

Comment: Your new example has the keys you want always being the next-to-last.  Is that invariant, or are you just really bad at coming up with sufficiently general examples? ;-)  You need to explain how the original camp column becomes the new camp column, whether by some rule or by comparison with an explicitly specified list.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print df
                 camp  value
0         abcd_gr_yxz      5
1         efgh_kr_ijk     10
2   hjssaasd_kr_adsad     15
3        asdas_kr_asd      2
4         asd_fr_asda     12
5  adklasdj_gr_asdsad      3

ABR = ['_gr_', '_kr_', '_fr_']

for x in ABR:
    df.loc[df['camp'].str.contains(x), 'camp'] = x
print df 
   camp  value
0  _gr_      5
1  _kr_     10
2  _kr_     15
3  _kr_      2
4  _fr_     12
5  _gr_      3

print df.groupby('camp')['value'].sum().reset_index()
   camp  value
0  _fr_     12
1  _gr_      8
2  _kr_     27
```

Or [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
ABR = ['_gr_', '_kr_', '_fr_']

s = '(' + '|'.join(ABR) + ')'
print s
(_gr_|_kr_|_fr_)

df['camp'] = df['camp'].str.extract(s, expand=False)

df = df.groupby('camp', as_index=False)['value'].sum()
df['camp'] = df['camp'].str.strip('_')
print df
  camp  value
0   fr     12
1   gr      8
2   kr     27
```

Comment: Yes but then I would need two loops. One for the list as well. Isn't there any easier way to do this in one row? using pandas replace/extract etc functions

Comment: can you accept my answer if is helpful so it doesn't remain unanswered, there will be an empty tick mark at the top left of my answer, thanks

Comment: But it's not the desired output